# Flutter: Showing both helpText and labelText in TextFormField

Tags: flutter

I am trying to build a login page using Flutter.

I want to have both hintText and labelText shown for the TextFormField that I'm using, however it only shows me the labelText when I click on the field, that is, when the cursor is in that field.

```dart
  TextFormField(
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'example@email.com',
    labelText: 'Username',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

---

*How it looks initially:*
[image: form]

---

*How it looks after I click on it:*
[image: form with cursor]

Answer (score 0):

You set `autofocus: true` to to make it focused immediately after the page has been rendered.

```
  TextFormField(
    autofocus: true,
    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
    decoration: const InputDecoration(
    hintText: 'example@email.com',
    labelText: 'Username',
    labelStyle: TextStyle(
      color: Colors.blue,
      ),
    ),
  );
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no default properties for it but you can try with this.

```
    return Scaffold(
        body: Center(
            child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Column(
                mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
                children: <Widget>[
                CustomTextFormField(
                    labelText: 'EMAIL',
                    hintText: 'example@email.com',
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: (t) {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),

                CustomTextFormField(
                    labelText: 'PASSWORD',
                    hintText: 'Enter password',
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: (t) {},
                ),
                SizedBox(height: 8),

                CustomTextFormField(
                    labelText: 'NAME',
                    hintText: 'Enter name',
                    keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                    validator: (t) {},
                )
                ],
            ),
            )));
```

Created on CustomTextFormField class

```
        import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

        class CustomTextFormField extends StatelessWidget {

            final TextEditingController controller;
            final String hintText;
            final String labelText;
            final TextInputType keyboardType;
            final Function(String) validator;
            final bool obscureText;

            CustomTextFormField({
            this.controller,
            this.hintText,
            this.labelText,
            this.keyboardType, 
            this.validator,     
            this.obscureText: false
            });

        @override
        Widget build(BuildContext context) {

            final theme = Theme.of(context);

            return Theme(
            data: theme.copyWith(
                primaryColor: theme.accentColor, 
                hintColor: Colors.grey[500], 
                errorColor: Colors.redAccent,
            ),
            child: Container(
                width: double.infinity,
                child: Column(
                crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                children: <Widget>[
                    Text(
                    labelText, 
                    textAlign: TextAlign.start, 
                    style: TextStyle(
                        color: theme.primaryColor, 
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, 
                        fontSize: 15
                    )
                    ),
                    TextFormField(
                    cursorColor: Colors.grey[850],
                    style: TextStyle(color: Colors.grey[850]),
                    controller: controller,
                    decoration: InputDecoration(
                        hintText: hintText,
                        enabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.primaryColor)),
                        focusedBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.primaryColor)),
                        disabledBorder: UnderlineInputBorder(borderSide: BorderSide(color: theme.primaryColor))
                    ),
                    keyboardType: keyboardType,
                    obscureText: obscureText,
                    validator: validator,
                    ),            
                ],
                ),
            )
            );
        }
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Add floatingLabelBehavior: FloatingLabelBehavior.always to InputDecoration
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uMxbx.png)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).